# write xmp data to all jpeg files in a folder

Tags: bash, shell, exiftool

can someone point me in the right direction if i need this

`exiftool -tagsfromfile XYZ.xmp -all:all XYZ.jpg`

to work for hundreds of jpgs? so i have a folgeder with houndreds of jpegs and xmps with the same name but different file ending (xmp and jpeg). what would be the elegant way to go through all of them and replace XYZ with the actual filename?

i want / need to do this in a shell on osx.

do in need something like a for loop? or is there any direct way in the shell?

Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Your command will be

```
exiftool -r --ext xmp -tagsfromfile %d%f.xmp -all:all /path/to/files/
```

See [Metadata Sidecar Files example #15](https://exiftool.org/metafiles.html#EX15).

The [`-r` (`-recurse`) option](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) allows recursion into subdirectories.  Remove it if recursion is not desired.

The [`-ext` (`-extension`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ext-EXT---ext-EXT--extension) is used to prevent the copying from the XMP files back onto themselves.

The `%d` variable is the directory of the file currently being processed.  The `%f` variable is the base filename without the extension of that file.  Then `xmp` is used as the extension.  The result creates a file path to a corresponding XMP file in the same directory for every image file found.  This will work for any writable file found (see [FAQ #16](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q16)).

This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.

You do not want to loop exiftool as shown in the other answers.  Exiftool's biggest performance hit is the startup time and looping it will increase the processing time. This is [Exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3).

Answer (score 0):

solved it by doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="$1/*.jpg"
for f in $FILES; do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    #cat "$f"
    FILENAME="${f%%.*}"
    echo $FILENAME
    # exiftool -tagsfromfile "$FILENAME".xmp -all:all "$FILENAME".jpg
    exiftool -overwrite_original_in_place -ext jpg -tagsFromFile "$FILENAME".xmp -@ xmp2exif.args -@ xmp2iptc.args '-all:all' '-FileCreateDate<XMP-photoshop:DateCreated' '-FileModifyDate<XMP-photoshop:DateCreated' "$FILENAME".jpg

  else
    echo "Warning: Some problem with \"$f\""
  fi

done
```

Comment: This is [Exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3).  Looping is unnecessary due to exiftool's powerful batch features and doing so will increase the processing time.

Comment: Another note.  The [`-overwrite_original_in_place` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original_in_place) option is slower than the [`-overwrite_original` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original), as exiftool has to write rewrite the file twice.  See [this exiftool forums post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=14297.msg77017#msg77017).  Unless you are using a Mac and need to keep the `XAtt`/`MDItem` file system attributes or on Windows using Alternate Data Streams, it's better to use the `-overwrite_original` option.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant and easy way, IMHO, is to use **GNU Parallel** to do them all in parallel:

```
parallel --dry-run exiftool -tagsfromfile {.}.xmp -all:all {} ::: *.jpg
```

If that looks correct, remove `--dry-run` and run again to do it for real.

`{}` just means *"the current file"*

`{.}` just means *"the current file without its extension"*

`:::` is just a separator followed by the names of the files you want **GNU Parallel** to process

---

You can install **GNU Parallel** on **macOS** with **homebrew**:

```
brew install parallel
```